# How to pass custom field value from Cart Page to Checkout Page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-checkout

I created one custom drop-down type field in the Estimate Shipping and Tax section on Cart Page Now I want to pass this custom drop-down type field value in the checkout page when I go to the checkout page. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ways to do that

1. you are on the cart page then you have added field value in the `sales_flat_quote` table and get the same thing on checkout page
2. Otherwise you have to set session value from the cart page and the same thing gets on the checkout page.